# How to restrict some of its features from end-users in Reports Winforms Devexpress?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, report

I created Standard Report Designer edit by end-users from this documentation [XtraReports](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument1764)

I want to restrict some of its controls like creating new Label, line, tables & Data Source. End-users just want to edit content in that XtraReports. How to restrict it ?

Comment: Just make a bool, and if the bool is true people aren't restricted.
When it's false people are restricted.

Comment: Hi, Where to make a bool ? Am new to devexpress tool how to check bool ?

Comment: Apparently XtraReports has it's own methods to restrict things.
Monil Gandhi has the right answer for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you need to either [Override toolbox](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/CustomDocument2552) or need to [Override XRControl drag and drop behaviour](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q144854) to restrict user from using selected XRControls.

Comment: Hi, I have 2 question 1) How to create controls like "label", "Line" in this code ? `// A custom control.
public class MyControl : XRControl {
    // ...
}`

Comment: 2) How to hide 1)Compnent Tray, 2)Status Bar, 3)main Menu, 4)layout Tool Bar and how to customize that to hide controls from 1)Tool Bar & 2) Mail Tool Bar ?

Answer (score 1):

you can define custom XRControl as below:

```
<DefaultBindableProperty("Number"), ToolboxBitmap(GetType(XRNumericLabel))> _
    Public Class XRNumericLabel
        Inherits XRLabel
        Private myNumber As Integer 

        <SRCategory(ReportStringId.CatData), DefaultValue(0), Bindable(True)> _
        Public Overridable Property Number() As Integer 
            Get 
                Return myNumber
            End Get 
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                myNumber = Value
            End Set 
        End Property 

        <Browsable(False), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), Bindable(False)> _
        Public Overrides Property Text() As String 
            Get 
                Return myNumber.ToString()
            End Get 
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                Dim i As Integer 

                If Integer.TryParse(Value, i) Then 
                    myNumber = i
                Else 
                    Throw New ArgumentException("This text can't be converted to a number!")
                End If 
            End Set 
        End Property 
    End Class
```

[Create custom XRControl Step by step tutorial](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2607) .

[Hide component tray](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/CustomDocument5225).